# JAXB generated class field is abstract

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have generated class from xsd file.

This class contains field with abstract class. This abstract class has two different implementations. Let's call is Impl1CLass and Impl2Class.

I cannot modify xsd schemas, I cannot modify generated classes.

All I need to do is when jaxb marshal this class and abstract field has null value, I need to get something like this:

```
<dep xsi:type="Impl1Class" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Thi field in generated class looks like this:

```
protected Dep dep;
```

Dep is abstract class.

So I need to set that this is nil and type is specific one (Impl1Class)

I tried to create XmlAdapter with BoundType as abstract class and ValueType is JAXBElement but there was no luck since it reuires default non-arg constructor but JAXBElement doesn't have such one.

REMARK. Other words I would like to set xsi:type when xsi:nil="true". How can I do that?

Here are generated classes

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "DepartmentKey"
)
@XmlSeeAlso({GroupDepartmentKey.class, EnterpriseDepartmentKey.class})
public abstract class DepartmentKey {
    public DepartmentKey() {
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "GroupDepartmentKey",
    propOrder = {"serviceProviderId", "groupId", "name"}
)
public class GroupDepartmentKey extends DepartmentKey {
    @XmlElement(
        required = true
    )
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String serviceProviderId;
    @XmlElement(
        required = true
    )
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String groupId;
    @XmlElement(
        required = true
    )
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String name;
    ......
}
```

In the target class there field without any annotations

```
protected DepartmentKey department;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set null using setter method while making the call.

```
Impl1Class impl1Class = new Impl1Class();
imple1Class.setDep(null);
```

Is setter method available with you? If not, you might need to subclass **Impl1Class** and set **Dep** to null.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorrry, I didn't get you. I do not have setter. So you suggest to extend Impl1Class (which is actually sub instance of Dep class) and add setter to set Dep to itself?

Comment: @Dmitriy Can you share the code of Dep and Impl1Class? Whichever class is a wrapper for Dep class can set the Dep to null. That's what I meant by my answer.

Comment: I modified question